# node.js elasticsearch multiple hosts

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

In my node application i have used "`Elasticsearch`" for data retrieval. When i connecting to only 1 host it works fine.

for ex:

```
try {
        elasticSearchClient = new ElasticSearchClient({
        host: 'xxx.xxx.x.xxxx',
        port: '9200'
    });
} catch (err) {
    console.log('err=' + err);
}
```

But when i tried to connect to multiple hosts(instance) i am getting error:

For ex:

```
var serverOptions = {
    hosts:[

        {
            host: 'xxx.xxx.x.xxx',
            port: 9200
        },{
            host: 'xxx.xxx.x.xxx',
            port: 9200
        }]
};

elasticSearchClient = new ElasticSearchClient(serverOptions);
```

Error:

```
ECONN REFUSED: socket hang up
```

I am using "`elsaticsearchclient`' node package. Help me to solve this. Thanks in advance..

EDIT:

Actually 1 host is up and another host is down. So when 1 of the host is down i have to redirect to another host.. How can i achieve this??

Answer (score 0):

`hosts` should be an array of full URLs. So do the following:

```
elasticSearchClient = elasticsearch.Client({
    hosts: serverOptions.hosts.map(function (server) {
        return 'http://' + serverOptions.user + ':' + serverOptions.password + '@' + server.host + ':' + server.port;
    })
}),
```

Comment: Thannks.. But u r using 'elasticsearch' package, but i am using 'elasticsearchclient' package.. so if use your above code.i dont have .on method..

Comment: You didn't mention which client you have used so I assumed you're using the official module, not a third party. I suggest you do so.

Comment: Usually the socket hangup issue occurs due to the remote server closing the connection. Usually it's because your client server isn't whitelisted to connect to the remote server.

Comment: Thanks. But when i connect the 2 hosts separately as single instance at once its working fine,, But when i connect through multiple hosts only i am facing this problem.

Comment: I suppose the reason can be that these two hosts don't belong to the same cluster which is why when connecting to the second one it terminates the connection. Can you open the `/_plugin/head/` and see if all hosts see each other.